# Unable to deploy Grails app to Tomcat 8 with JDK mismatch: 404 The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, deployment, java-7

I found I am unable to deploy simple helloworld web application, created with Grails, onto Tomcat. It looks like Tomcat does not see application at all and regarding just a bunch of files.

I have tried to put static HTML into application and Tomcat serves it.

I have tried to set logback of webapplication (in groovy) to more verbose level and nothing happens, as if Tomcat ignores it.

**UPDATE**

I have removed details since the major problem appeared to be clear: it was because `Tomcat` on the server was running under Java `1.7` and on the development computer I was compiling for `1.8`

But the question persists, because I can't understand an effect: how can it happen, that target JDK mismatch causes no error message and no exceptions, but just silent nothing happening?

Comment: Is the tomcat service running? And what JDK version are you using? I´ve had trouble when using java 8 in some tomcat versions. It is also possible, albeit pretty unlikely, that you firewall is blocking your app.

Comment: Tomcat is running, manager is running, application is listed (under folder name), but opening it causes 404

Comment: did you have a look to TOMCAT_HOME/logs/catalina.out ? maybe during the start of tomcat there is an error which doesn't prevent tomcat from starting

Comment: I looked. Tomcat DOES run, because I can view it's pages, like Manager.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about starting tomcat, deploying and managing apps on it. Check out [official documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/appdev/index.html).

But first check out this default webapps manager: http://localhost:8080/manager/
(but I think you will need to add tomcat user before you can get it)

Comment: Tomcat is running, manager is running, application is listed (under folder name), but opening it causes 404

Comment: Check standard log in /tomcat/logs/catalina.out. If you find any incomprehensible problem, paste it.

Comment: No error message there, just a message that app was registered successfully

Comment: Hard to say - show full log. You can also try to redeploy it through admin console and restart tomcat (in case of any leaks)

Answer (score 0):

In your grails application, look into two places:

1. `application.properties` and look for `app.name`, usually the context path is same `app.name`
2. `BuildConfig.groovy`and look for `grails.project.war.file`. This will tell you how zip file name is structured.

If you have specific set of properties in your `Config.groovy` file, make sure that you add environment name in your `war` command. Ex `war test`

Comment: I don't have `application.properties`, I have `application.yml`, it has no special config for name.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried  http://myhost/MyApp-0.1 ?
If you dont change anything in the Config.groovy, the route is similar but running over the 80 port.